# How to use regular expression to match everything like /n, /t, and etc

Tags: regex

So I am trying to make some string plain. The strings contains "\t", "\n", and etc. I want to use regex to match everything that start with a "\", and end with a lower case letter. I know `r'/n'` can match all "\n", but `\[a-z]`, can't match all the cases.

Comment: If you are trying to match all whitespace, you might not need to match the idea of `\[a-z]` but rather just use `\s`. See [here](https://regexone.com/lesson/whitespaces)

Comment: Dot symbol - `.` - match everything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the regex. Try both of them below. One of them will work.

```
\\[a-z],  
\\\[a-z],
```